# Odoo 11 : Problem while creating compute field in sale.order.line model

Tags: python-3.x, field, odoo, odoo-11

I want to put the **bom_id** of each products in sale.order.line model, to do that, I use computed field to get the bom id (mrp.bom). I need that for specified development where the goal is to show consummed materials  according to company's calculation before going to prodction. Here is the code:

```
bom_id = fields.Integer(
    string='Bom ID',
    compute='_get_bom_id'
)

@api.multi
def _get_bom_id(self):
    bom_obj = self.env['mrp.bom']
    for record in self:
        bom_obj_id = bom_obj.search([('product_id', '=', record.product_id.id)])
        if bom_obj_id:
            record.bom_id = bom_obj_id.id
        else:
            record.bom_id = 0
```

The problem is that the field is not created in sale.order.line model, but if i remove the compute argument, it works. I already update the module, check in pgadmin, ... I know that the issue is related to the code but don't know where. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: computed field should be defined in the view. is your view have computed field defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the field you have created is wrong, it should be a *Many2one* instead of an *Integer*:

```
bom_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='mrp.bom',
    string='Bom ID',
    compute='_get_bom_id'
)
```

You have also forgotten the `api.depends` decorator. In your case, the value should be recomputed each time the field `product_id` changes.

In addition, a computed field always values `False` before executing its compute method, so if in your compute method the workflow does not give a value to the field, it still values `False`, which means that lines like `record.bom_id = 0` or `record.bom_id = False` are useless.

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('product_id')
def _get_bom_id(self):
    bom_obj = self.env['mrp.bom']
    for record in self:
        bom_obj_id = bom_obj.search([('product_id', '=', record.product_id.id)])
        if bom_obj_id:
            record.bom_id = bom_obj_id.id
```

Comment: I updated the module but it still doesn't work. No related error(s) in odoo.log, error but not related to it : bad query: b'ALTER TABLE "mrp_production" ALTER COLUMN "date_planned" SET NOT NULL' //// psycopg2.IntegrityError: ERREUR:  la colonne « date_planned » contient des valeurs NULL. For information, the model sale.order.line already contains 62959 records.

Comment: Exactly, that error is because `date_planned` is a NOT NULL column in PostgreSQL and you have at least one record with that column value NULL. Of course, the problem is that we had forgotten the `api.depends` decorator. Your field only depends on `product_id`, so my edit will solve your problem.

Comment: And another addtional info: If you want the values in database as column, use `store=True` on field definition. Computed fields are per default not stored in database.

Comment: sorry for the waiting, no internet connection outside my office. @CZoellner, it works. Thank you both of you.

Comment: @m0r7y I am glad we had helped you. Please, set the answer as correct to close your question.